# bluetooth is not turning on

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

My Bluetooth does not turn on no matter what I do
[Bluetooth off although the bar says it is on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZjaE.png)

This is the output of "sudo systemctl status bluetooth"

> ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
> Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-05-30 05:36:53 +03; 6min ago
> Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
> Main PID: 2596 (bluetoothd)
> Status: "Running"
> Tasks: 1 (limit: 618623)
> Memory: 1.5M
> CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
> └─2596 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`